# Can't read JSON data in java script (node JS - Express) that Created with JSONUtility in Unity

Tags: json, node.js, express, unity-game-engine

This is my put request in Unity:

```
UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Put(baseUrl + "miniGame1s/", JsonUtility.ToJson(cardsToSend));
```

And the "cardsToSend" is an object form class below:

```
[Serializable]
class Cards
{
    public string uid;
    public List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();
}
[Serializable]
class Card
{
    public int index;
    public int theCard;
    public bool theAnswer;
    public int theState;
    public bool playerAnswer;
    public float answerMoment;
    public float timeAfterAnswer;
    public float scoreAfterAnswer;
    public int validOrNot;
}
```

And this is the code in the server that written in Node js and Express:

```
app.put('/api/miniGame1s',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    const objectSchema = Joi.object().keys({
        index: Joi.number().required(),
        theCard: Joi.number().required(),
        theAnswer: Joi.boolean().required(),
        theState: Joi.number().required(),
        playerAnswer: Joi.boolean().required(),
        answerMoment: Joi.number().required(),
        timeAfterAnswer: Joi.number().required(),
        scoreAfterAnswer: Joi.number().required(),
        validOrNot: Joi.number().integer().required()
    });
    const arraySchema = {
        uid: Joi.string().required(),
        cards: Joi.array().items(objectSchema)
    };

    const result = Joi.validate(req.body, arraySchema);
    if(result.error) return res.status(400).send(result.error.details[0].message);
    else{
        thatGame1InProgressIndex = game1sInProgress.findIndex(g => g.uid == req.body.uid);
        console.log('Index: ' + thatGame1InProgressIndex);
        for(let i = 0; i < req.body.cards.length;i++)
        {
            game1sInProgress[thatGame1InProgressIndex].cards[req.body.cards[i].index] = req.body.cards[i];
        }

        // TODO: validating incomming info and set the validation parameter

        // TODO: generate new cards and send them to client.
        let newCards = {
            uid: req.body.uid,
            cards: []
        };
        for(let i = 0; i < 10 ;i++)
        {
            let card = CreateACard(game1sInProgress[thatGame1InProgressIndex].cards[game1sInProgress[thatGame1InProgressIndex].cards.length-1].theCard, game1sInProgress[thatGame1InProgressIndex].cards.length);
            game1sInProgress[thatGame1InProgressIndex].cards.push(card);
            newCards.cards.push(card);
        }
        res.send(newCards);
    }
});
```

Now, the server code is incomplete yet. ( that's not the issue )
the problem is that I can't retrieve the JSON object in the server.

I tried different things, like use ToString() in unity instead of JSON.ToJson(), or Parsing the "req.body" in the server with JSON.parse(), or things like this.

In the best case, I will give the error: "uid" is required
that is the Joi Validation error. that means it can't reveal the parameters of Object.

I tried to Send the same request with the same data to the server with POSTMAN app. and it works.

I think the problem is that the structure of the JSON that Produced by JSONUtility, is the problem.

Any Help Will Be Appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be that the content-type is wrong and you need to set your own UploadHandler or call SetRequestHeader on the UnityWebRequest.

Comment: Yes, it was a problem with request header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I should say that this link was so useful:

[UnityWebRequest.Post(url, jsonData) sending broken Json](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unitywebrequest-post-url-jsondata-sending-broken-json.414708/)

And the solution is that you need to set the "content-type" to "application/json". this way the Express can realize the JSON object and read it perfectly. to do so, add this line after creating your request and before sending it to server:

```
request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```